# Evaluating word2vec using SimLex-999 and wordsim - key error

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embedding, evaluate

I have a strange problem while trying to evaluate my Word2Vec model in Italian. 
I'm using this data http://www.leviants.com/ira.leviant/MultilingualVSMdata.html

I'm getting this error `

```html
 model.wv.evaluate_word_pairs(pairs= "...MWS353_Italian_tab.txt")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 1281, in evaluate_word_pairs
    ok_vocab = [(w, self.vocab[w]) for w in self.index2word[:restrict_vocab]]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 1281, in <listcomp>
    ok_vocab = [(w, self.vocab[w]) for w in self.index2word[:restrict_vocab]]
KeyError: 'di'
```

Now the strange part is that the word "di" is neither in my vocabulary nor in my txt file. What is wrong here? I thought it was a separator problem, tried tsv, tried to give the argument `="\t"`, nothing changed.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: That error seems to indicate that `'di'` is in the model's `.index2word` list, but not in the model's `.vocab` dictionary. (This wouldn't happen in normal operation, as the keys of the `.vocab` dict should be matched 1-for-1 with entries in the `.index2word` list.) So, it's an indication of an issue with the model, not your input file. Does `'di' in model.wv` .index2word` return `True`? Has this model been constructed or modified in any non-standard ways?

Comment: No, I literally copied the gensim tutorial. I have the same problem with the word "the" in an english model. My idea is that in .`index2word` list are still present words that have been discarded in the vocabulary because of subsampling. How could I remove these words from `index2word`?

Comment: No, every word that's in `index2word` should be in the `vocab` dict. And, the decision about what words to keep is done before subsampling. If not, there's a bug. If you can provide a minimal example of creating a situation where for any word *x*, `x in model.wv.index2word` returns `True` but `x in model.wv.vocab` returns `False`, I could figure out what's triggering the discrepancy.

Comment: `if "the" in model.wv.index2word:
    print("The word is in index2word")
else:
        print("Ups, can't find it")



if "the" in model.wv.vocab:
        print("The word is in vocab")
else:
    print("Ups, can't find it")
The word is in index2word
The word is in vocab` Mmmmmmm now I'm even more confused....

Comment: But what about `'di'`?

Comment: Just came back on this, sorry. It's the same for the word "d", so I really don't understand the issue here

Comment: What's the same for `'di'` - the (expected) behavior you showed for `'the'`, or something else? (If you're providing both lines of code & their output, it may be clearer to extend your question with more info.) But most importantly: If you can provide a **complete & minimal** example of creating a situation where for any word x, `x in model.wv.index2word` returns `True` but `x in model.wv.vocab` returns False, I could then figure out what's triggering the discrepancy.

Comment: `di` is indeed in `index2word` but not in `wv.vocab`. Same for the word `Salvini`, that is a word that occur more than 2000 times in my corpus. What is even stranger is that I ran again the evaluation, with the default `wordsim353` provided by Gensim, and it worked. But it does not make any sense, because the file is in English and my corpus in Italian. Still very confused

Comment: If you can make a small example that demonstrates the problem, I suspect that either (1) you'll realize the error during that exercise; or (2) seeing such a compact example, I'll be able to see error (or bug) quickly. (It doesn't sound like either the code or data or runtime will be very large!) But, given this latest report – an evaluation in another lang inexplicably working! – there's now likely a more foundational error here with filenames/steps/etc, not even visible in your question/comments. So to help further, really need a fresh, compact, complete recipe-to-reproduce.